# Create PowerShell script for Oracle DB automation

Tags: sql, oracle, powershell, plsql

I want to create Powershell script for oracle database automation having some following steps regarding automation would be mention:-

> 1. Drop the Schema in DB (Drop user username cascade)
> 2. Restore clean DB (impdp from dumpfiles)
> 3. Run configuration task (script)
> 4. Impdp statistics from another environment into DB
> 5. Restore/Apply stats from another environment (dbms_stats.import_schema_statistics)
> 6. Backup stats after step 4 (dbms_stats.gather_schema_statistics)

Please help me to create sample powershell script in which all the steps should be mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example script for drop user with tablespace `tablespace_username` including contents and  datafiles
usage `./drop_user.ps1  username`

```
param(
[string]$name_user = ""
)

Write-Host "NAME_USER: $name_user"

##!!!!! ORA-01940: cannot drop a user that is currently connected
## USER must disconnect before drop user!!!

#Dropping Users
#Dropping users is very straightforward and is accomplished with the drop user command. The
#only parameters are the username to be dropped and the cascade option; any objects owned by
#the user must be explicitly dropped or moved to another schema if the cascade option is not used.

$username_dba = "system"
$password_dba = "manager"
$tnsalias_db = "test-ecdu"
$full_name_user=$name_user   
#
$user_tablespace = "tablespace_"
$default_tablespace_user = $user_tablespace+$name_user
#
Write-Host "USER default_tablespace: $default_tablespace_user"


#Make SQL DROP TABLESPACE
# The database also automatically drops from the operating system any Oracle-managed datafiles and tempfiles in the tablespace. 
#Other datafiles and tempfiles are not removed from the operating system unless you specify INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES.
$sqlQuery_drop_tablespace = @"
set NewPage none
set heading off
set feedback off
WHENEVER SQLERROR continue
DROP TABLESPACE  $default_tablespace_user INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES
;
"@

#Degug display "SQL Tablespace: $sqlQuery_drop_tablespace"
#Specify CASCADE to drop all objects in the user's schema before dropping the user. 
#You must specify this clause to drop a user whose schema contains any objects.
Write-Host "SQL Drop Tablespace: $sqlQuery_drop_tablespace"
#
$sqlQuery_drop_user = 
@"

DROP USER $full_name_user CASCADE 
;
exit
"@


$sqlQuery = $sqlQuery_drop_tablespace + $sqlQuery_drop_user

# Degug display  $sqlQuery = $sqlQuery_drop_tablespace + $sqlQuery_drop_user
Write-Host $sqlQuery   
$sqlOutput = $sqlQuery | sqlplus -silent $username_dba/$password_dba@$tnsalias_db

# Degug display result SQL
Write-Host  $sqlOutput
```

Comment: Thanks for help me. But you are writing script for 1st step only not all. For all the steps what I have to write in the script. Please help me.

Comment: Well, when I have enough free time, I will help you.

Comment: Yeah sure. Thanks  for help me, remaining process will follow as is it that mention in script. only i have to add SQL query.